# I am trying to get a users from firestore and store them in Map in javascript but for some reasone the map is empty

Tags: javascript

So the user Object has 5 attributes firstName , lastName,email,password and city.

I am getting the users with a method in class Users which is :

```
  getUsersData () {
    const usersMap = new Map()
    this.users.get().then((data) => {
      data.docs.forEach(user=> {
        const {email , password} = user.data();
        usersMap.set(email,password);
      });
    });
    return usersMap;
  }
```

which returns this in chrome console:

```
Map(0) {}
[[Entries]]
0: {"mehdiboujid@gmail.com" => "dqdqwdq"}
size: (...)
__proto__: Map
```

I am trying to use credentials in a Map because every user will have a unique email which will be the key to the map.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you expect the output to be?

Comment: i forgot the await keyword as the answer mentioned because as u can see in the first output i pasted it has an entry which has a value but if u log the size of the map it will return 0 for some reason i am trying to get better at javascript to prepare for react !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.users.get()` is async you will have to `await` the result before returning the `usersMap`.

```js
async getUsersData() {
  const usersMap = new Map()
  await this.users.get()
    .then((data) => {
      data.docs.forEach(user => {
        const { email, password } = user.data();
        usersMap.set(email, password);
      });
    });
  return usersMap;
}
```

Comment: Oh it actually worked ,Thanks a lot i was missing out the await keyword i should revise more the async await part of javascript.